# Javascript to limit the number of file uploaded input file

Tags: javascript, html, grails, file-upload, input

I want to limit the number of files uploaded to 3. 
Im new on this, so please anyone can help?

Here my code:

```js
$('#fileinput').change(function(){
    if(this.files.length>3)
        alert('to many files')
});
```

```html
<input id="fileinput" type="file"  name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have generally works in a browser supporting the files apis.
Here's your code, made to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fileinput').change(function() {
    if (this.files.length > 3)
      alert('to many files')
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6vw0maLb/2/